# NSLog messages of my application are not coming to /var/log/system.log. I am using macOS Sierra 10.12.3) on VmWare

Tags: logging, macos-sierra, nslog

I am not able to get NSLog messages on /var/log/system.log. Where the messages are going can someone please help me out. Or is there any configuration missing.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with macOS Sierra / iOS 10 Apple introduced a new unified logging mechanism, which NSLog is redirected to. This logging mechanism doesn't store messages in /var/log/system.log anymore. It stores messages in a binary form elsewhere. You're supposed to use either the Console app or the `log` command to view the logs.

By the way, the Console app has been reworked, and it's pretty good.

For more details, please, see WWDC 2016 - [Session 721: Unified Logging and Activity Tracing](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721/)

Comment: I saw this session, and it gives absolutely no answer to the basic question: WHERE ARE MY LOGS. I cannot find my NSLog() messages in the Console - the only thing I can do is see the LIVE if I click the device, and search for my App's process. The moment my app quits - they disappear forever. I find this session so frustrating - because it only burdens me with new APIs and responsibilities - but without any ability to save logs, archive them, extract them or otherwise use them. Some VERY BASIC information is missing there. I will be forever thankful if you try to complete the gap.

Comment: @MottiShneor This post should help you: https://blackbagtech.com/blog/2017/09/22/accessing-unified-logs-image . I've also summarized it at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49081487/548975