# Xcode 9, where are my NSLog()s going? Not showing in Xcode console or Console.app

Tags: ios, xcode, nslog

I'm trying to do some basic logging while I work on an app. I tossed some `NSLog()`s into my code, but nothing is being printed to the Xcode console below. Literally nothing, not even some startup info as the app launches, etc.

I've got my Xcode console set to display `All Output` and I've got the variable inspector and the Console open:

[image]

[image]

I heard about Logging changes and that a new Console.app was introduced that would let me view the logs on the simulators as well, so I thought maybe the logs would show up over there, but while I do so lots of system messages happening I don't see the NSLog()s that I'm making.

Am I missing something? Is there a new setting I need to flip? Where can I see my NSLog()s?

EDIT:

I was doing this with an iOS 11 simulator and got no console output. When I switched to an iOS 9 simulator then I got all of the console output.

Comment: Are you sure your debugger is correctly connected? Do your breakpoints still work?

Comment: @Sulthan Yes, my breakpoints are functioning correctly. I just double-checked to be sure.

Comment: I was doing this with an iOS 11 simulator and got no console output. When I switched to an iOS 9 simulator then I got all of the console output.

Comment: That's weird. I can tell you there was no big change and my logs are still working properly. Make sure your Xcode is using the correct xcode tools (that is, the Xcode 9 tools).

Comment: @KennyWyland check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886600/ios-10-doesnt-print-nslogs

Comment: I've seen this as an intermittent phenomenon. Next run, they usually start printing again.

Comment: Had the issue quite often on Xcode 8, it usually required restarting Xcode.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Figured it out. It's not an intermittent issue or one that can just be fixed with a restart. It's a Run configuration issue.

Click on the Run Scheme selector in the top left of Xcode's toolar.

Click Manage Schemes.

[image]

Click on your main App Project.

Click the Edit button in the bottom left.

[image]

Uncheck `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE`.

Click Close.

Viola. All your console logs come back.

[image]

Comment: Kenny, what is the full name CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIO... when I try to enter this it doesn't show up automatically

Comment: @greg it's CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS. hopefully you found it in the last year though. :)