# Xcode 9.3, NSLog not printing but print works

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode9.3

In my app, all logs of the Swift code (print) is printing properly, but in the Objective c log (NSLog) not printing. 
NB: I've tried this one 
[iOS 10 doesn't print NSLogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886600/ios-10-doesnt-print-nslogs)

Comment: Have you checked with Breakpoints?

Comment: do you have any third party libraries in your project ?

Comment: Did you try this ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47004127/xcode-9-where-are-my-nslogs-going-not-showing-in-xcode-console-or-console-ap?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: KeyurTailor , yes I've checked it, the line executes but prints nothing. 
NiravKotecha , Yes my project has some third party libraries like AFNetworking ,PhotoTweaks,LUAutocompleteView and so on.
QuentinRth , I did that, but it didn't work.